# How do I modify the src attribute of an iframe tag before it executes?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, dom-events, mutation-observers

I'd like to create a **JavaScript** function that detects the addition of an `iframe` tag in the **DOM**, which manages to modify its `src` attribute before it can execute, so that it can execute with the new `src` attribute.

To try and achieve this, I used the **MutationObserver** interface like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>MutationObserver Example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    function test() {
      const config = {
        subtree: true,
        childList: true
      };

      const callback = (mutationList) => {
        for (const mutation of mutationList) {
          if (mutation.type === "childList") {

            for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
              if (node.tagName && node.src && node.tagName.toLowerCase() === "iframe") {
                node.src = "index8.html";
              }
              else {
                for (const div of node.querySelectorAll?.("div") || []) {
                  node.src = "index8.html";
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      };
      const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
      observer.observe(document.documentElement, config);
    };

    test();
  </script>

  <iframe src="index2.html"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

The **MutationObserver** interface has successfully detected the addition of an `iframe` tag in the **DOM** and manages to "modify" the `src` attribute. However, the `iframe` was executed with `src=index2.html`, not `index8.html`.

My goal is to place a "hook" when creating an `iframe`, and to modify the `src` attribute before the `iframe` is executed.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I can't find the details of the ordering in the spec, but it sounds like the mutation observer is called after the ifram is added and processed. So it observer, it can't change.

Comment: As mentioned above, its too late to prevent it from being loaded with the original `src`, because by definition, mutation "observer" events run after the fact it was inserted. Im guessing you, for some reason, don't have control of the code that creates this iframe in the first place? Depending on how it inserts it, you might be able to override the native function (like createElement) to capture this. But such a solution is terribly hacky. Its easier for us to help if you explain what the end goal is that you are trying to achieve and why.

Comment: @Barmar The observer has detected that the iframe tag has been added to the DOM, so it is executed before the tag. However, the iframe tag seems to run before the observer manages to change its src attribute. Is there no way to hook the execution of an iframe tag in order to execute code just before it?

Comment: @GérardHazebrouck To handle this scenario, you might consider intercepting the creation of the iframe at a lower level. One approach could be to override the document.createElement method to detect when an iframe is being created and modify its properties before it's added to the DOM.

Comment: "The observer has detected that the iframe tag has been added to the DOM, so it is executed before the tag". The second the iframe is added to the dom, the iframe already starts retreiving its `src`. So the opportunity to prevent it loading the original `src` is gone by the time the mutation event fires. This API will simply not do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @adsy In fact, I have no control over the code that creates this iframe. My aim is to insert JavaScript code into the HTML response of a server (e.g. facebook.com), and redirect all requests made by iframe tags (via their src attribute) to my own server, for example.

In other words, if there are iframe tags in the response from the facebook.com server, I'd like to be able to ensure that the requests made by the src attribute are not executed (to the facebook, google, etc. servers), in order to modify the value of this src attribute to redirect the request to my own server.

Comment: The only way to do this would be to use a debugger on the code that inserts the iframe, determine what native method it is using, then try to override this method with your own wrapper impl to catch the insertion before it *really* happens.

Comment: Alternative idea I just had: You might also be able to kinda use CSP, content security policy, to make it so iframes can only reach out to your own host. Then, when it is inserted, it will not be able to reach out to the original location (it will still try, and there will be an error in console, but not really any negative effects overall. It wont be able to reach the original src location). Then you can modify the src via mutation observer like before.

Comment: @talha2k adsy Thank you very much for your help. It sounds complex indeed. I'll look into it and see what I can do. If you have any draft code, I'm interested.

Comment: @adsy Your idea is brilliant! I'm going to give it a try!